# Which free software can convert Serial to Ethernet?

Tags: windows, software-rec, ethernet, tcpip

I'm using [Serial over Ethernet](http://www.virtualserialport.com/products/serial-over-ethernet/), but it's not free. Is there any free software that can do the same thing?

Comment: You want software that converts serial bus data and transmits it over ethernet?  Because your title makes no sense.

Comment: Have you looked at http://freecode.com/projects/serproxy ?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux I imagine [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) would allow you to forward the serial port over Ethernet. I don't know if any of the Windows ports of netcat would allow this though.

You may also need to do some extra work if you need an interface similar to the program you have linked to.